# Coding Style: should 80 chars per line be enough for everyone?

Tags: c, coding-style, indentation

Most texts about coding style suggest to limit the length of a single line of code to at most 80 characters. However, the vast majority of common output devices is perfectly capable of exceeding this limit.

Why is this limit still advocated so strictly?

**I.**

There are some cases where I can see an advantage due to increased readability, i.e. when returning the value of a boolean expression:

```
int is_foo(void *x)
{
        /* this would look like magic without linebreaks */

        return (isint(*x) && \
                (*x > 23) && \
                (x != 0xDEADBEEF) && \
                bar(*x));
 }
```

**II.**

On the other hand, I don't see an urgent need to split the following statement across multiple lines:

```
snprintf(buf, BUFSIZ, "The big brown fox makes this LOC exceed its %d character limit", 80);

/* is IMO superior to: */
snprintf(buf, BUFSIZ, \
         "The big brown fox makes this LOC exceed its %d character limit", \
         80);
```

**III.**

And of course, there are cases where line splitting is a bad excuse for the lack of a clear structure of the code:

```
for (i = 0, *foo = bar, hash_init(); \
     is_my_kungfu_already_that_old("bruce") && !list_empty(foo[i]); \
     ++i, ++j, --k, *p++ = *q--) {
        /* whatever */
}
```

Comment: This is totally subjective, there is no right answer. Voting to close.

Comment: C uses `;` to delimit statements so that you rarely need a line continuation character outside of macros.

Comment: @unwind: It's probably about as subjective as the other 1500 questions tagged "coding-style".

Comment: Personally I limit the length of my lines to the width of a 1920x1080 display less the default left-margin width of the IDE.  It's kind of the modern equivalent of the 80 character standard.

Comment: @aroth: Ouch. Don't you ever need to view side-by-side diffs?

Comment: This is also not something I worry about - The question I ask myself is only whether the code is readable and looks to make sense.  Generally, that means adding in line breaks for long SQL queries or whatever - but sometimes it means leaving a long line as well.

Comment: @Charles:  Yes, but horizontal scrolling is rarely an issue.  It's quite atypical for any line to actually reach that maximum length.  Besides, it's not like an 80-character wide terminal display could do side-by-side diffs either if the code was written with 80-character long lines.

Comment: @aroth: My point was that one of the great advantages of wide screens as that two-way and three-way side-by-side diffs work. As you said that a 1920 pixel display is the equivalent of the 80 character standard, I assumed that you meant that you try to fit most code to that width which would negate this advantage. But now you've said that that isn't what you meant, it invalidates my previous comment.

Comment: FWIW, I don't follow an 80 limit for my own choice, but neither do I pitch a fit when asked to write to a coding standard that demands it. Can be quite challenging in C++, though...

Comment: @Charles - When needed, I guess he could but the other source window on his **other** display. Works perfectly for side by side comparisons!  :-)

Comment: Some of us use netbooks. And even if I have a 2048-pixel-wide screen, that doesn't necessarily mean I want to occupy the whole thing with one window. It's just like the madness of making websites so horizontally bloated. I used to be able to keep a web browser on half my screen and terminals on the other half. Nowadays, the web is barely usable unless you maximize your browser, due to the *same broken line of thinking* as your question.

Comment: @R..: need clarification: so you're implying that it's still a Good Thing nowadays to adhere to the 80 char limit?

Comment: I think the important thing about 80char is that, again, it helps you keep windows side by side. But most modern displays are much larger than before, and can fit two >100char lines without a problem. So if the code is more readable with >80char, I'd use it. Specially in JS/JQuery, even a simple selector can go over 80char when you do proper tabbing and stuff. So strictly adhering to 80char might make the code much messier than helpful.

Comment: 80 char lines let me code on a 15" laptop, viewing two files side by side. If you always use a bigger screen, that's great, but your code will be hard for anyone with a smaller monitor or laptop to work with. Also, a line length limit helps encourage short parameter lists, not nesting too many levels of indentation, and other good habits.